# why does my Epson WF-7710 keep make paper jam?

Tags: printing, printer, paper

Every time I try to print with the above printer on both sides of the paper, once it prints one side and tries to switch, there is a bit of a noise (hard to describe) and then the paper reports paper jam. If I print only on one side, it seems to print fine.

What could be the problem? I did what the paper error suggested, and both checked at the rear and opened it up, and indeed there was a paper jam, but once I remove it, the same thing repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so I got bored a bit so decided to look into this more seriously.

I found this document: https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd53888.pdf discussing paper jam in the "duplexer".

That was a new concept to me, didn't know there is such thing. They explain there how to take it out. I took it out, and I felt there was something plasticy there that didn't quite click right. So I re-clicked it, put the duplexer back, and now I got two-sided printing!

So if you run into such trouble, do take out the duplexer, and check if all things lock in correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the printer serviced.

There is a mechanism that retracts the paper after it has printed one side and then feeds it back so the other side can be printed.

That mechanism has failed and either needs to be repaired or most likely replaced.

I hear my own printer flipping the page.

See if the repair is economical or whether it makes more sense to replace the printer.